# How do I grab a link for downstream rspec test from ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer

I'm building an integration/feature test where an invite email is generated, and in the rspec test I want to be able to grab the link then follow it for downstream testing.

Here is how I grab the email:

```
last_delivery = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
```

and the body appears as follows:

```
puts last_delivery.body

----==_mimepart_54cc1b76a8d12_d673ffe1c74c22869b6
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You have a pending invite!</h1>
    <p>To join, please follow the link below and login or signup.</p>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/invite/13">Your Invite</a>
  </body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_54cc1b76a8d12_d673ffe1c74c22869b6--
```

The id of the Invite will probably change between test runs, so is it possible and how can I extract the link to use to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) to parse the url from the link:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(last_delivery.body)
url = doc.css("a").map { |link| link[:href] }.first
```

Rather than this approach, why not just have a feature that sends the invite and another that simulates the user signing up via an invite link?

```
feature "User sends invite" do
  scenario "to a valid email address" do
    # ...
    expect(page).to have_content "Your invite was sent to user@example.com"
  end
end

feature "Invitee signs up" do
  scenario "by accessing an invite link" do
    invite = Invite.create
    visit invite_path(invite)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Hadn't thought to use Nokogiri here, that would work.  But using your advice to separate into another feature test, I have a habit of trying to write features in a long strings when I could simplify.  Thanks.